# Can I Add an extra variable to String.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

This is just a question of curiosity. But im wondering if I can add an extra variable in front of String.prototype.

For example:

`$.String.prototype.functionName = function(){};`

Of course I relize this doesnt work. But can I make it work somehow? I would like a syntax like:

`$("Hi").functionName();`

The, jQuery syntax, just with string inside of the () instead of a selector.

I would like the `$` to be required.

Since:

```
String.prototype.functionName = function(){};
var $ = String;
$("Hi").functionName();
```

Works, but it makes it so the $ isn't required, so "Hi".functionName() works.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: If you want to keep good relationship with jQuery, don't do this.

Comment: No, I dont want it to keep good relationship with jQuery. Just want to know how to do this.

Comment: `"hi".functionName()` is just ok. `$` is not required.

Comment: @xdazz: Why would jQuery care?

Comment: @amnotiam The op want this work together with jQuery. For example what will `$("div").functionName()` pretend to be?

Comment: @xdazz: Oh, I think OP just wants to know how to do it. I don't think it will actually be used alongside jQuery, or at least not under the same namespace, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @amnotiam You are right since he accepted your answer :)

Comment: I did accept but I can't seem to get it to work with my list of functions on this: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/Hzkdg/9/..the error im getting is: `Uncaught TypeError: Object Hi has no method 'repeat'` Even though repeat is in the list. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what is meant by *"the jQuery syntax"*, but if you mean using the `$` variable as a reference to a function that manipulates strings, then that's pretty simple...

```
;(function(window, undefined) {
    var MyStringLib = function(s) { this.string = s; };

    window.$ = function(s) { return new MyStringLib(s); };

    MyStringLib.prototype.addFooBar = function() {
        this.string += "foobar";
        return this;
    };
    MyStringLib.prototype.reverse = function() {
        this.string = this.string.split('').reverse().join('');
        return this;
    };
    MyStringLib.prototype.get = function() {
        return this.string;
    };

})(this);
```

---

Then use the library like this...

```
var result = $("My name is ").addFooBar().reverse().get();

alert(result); // raboof si eman yM
```

Comment: Is there a way to put all the functions in a var? like: `var hi = {reverse: function(){}}` Thats how my current code works. And I tried doing it but nothing is working

Comment: @Shawn31313: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is somewhat confused.  If you had something like this

```
$.String.prototype.functionName = function(){};
```

you would have to address it like this:

```
(new $.String("Hi")).functionName();
```

(some parentheses are optional.)

If you want to be able to do something like this:

```
$("Hi").functionName();
```

then you would need to attach it like this:

```
$.prototype.functionName = function(){};
```

(Note that jQuery's magic `fn` parameter is just an alias to its constructor function's `prototype` property.)

What is your underlying goal here?